# Блоки в ряд, адаптация по ширине экрана

Tags: html, css

Помогите расположить три блока в строку на всю ширину экрана, так, чтобы левый и правый имели фиксированную ширину, а средний адаптивно сжимался до min-width. И чтобы они были намертво приклеены друг к другу.

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100px;">
  <div style="width: 100px;">1</div>
  <div style="min-width: 500px">2</div>
  <div style="width: 200px;">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Один из вариантов с float'ами (прибить й-ый и 3-ий по краям, а среднему дать оставшееся место):

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  min-width: 700px;
}

.div-1 {
  float: left;
  background: #FDD;
  width: 100px;
}

.div-3 {
  float: right;
  background: #DFD;
  width: 100px;
}

.div-2 {
  min-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 100px 0;
  background: #EEF;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div-1">1</div>
  <div class="div-3">3</div>
  <div class="div-2">2</div>
</div>
```